# AS400 sql clear screen

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I am new to working with an AS400 green screen terminal and I am running some queries through the STRSQL command.
However, I cannot figure out how to clear the terminal screen to get rid of the past queries that were run.

An analogy; if im running command prompt and the screen gets too cluttered, i can run 'cls' to clear the screen. Is there a simular command on AS400?

Comment: STRSQL isn't a "command prompt" exactly, and you'll possibly find that it's often not a good idea to clear the STRSQL history of statements. I can't recall ever wanting it cleared (in a couple decades of use).

Comment: WinSQL is a very nice tool to run queries against DB2/400

Answer (score 4):

You can press Shift-F1 (F13) and select option 3 "Remove all entries from current session".  Then press Enter to confirm.

Comment: Cool!  What OS version?

Comment: @BuckCalabro I think it's been that way "forever" and works at least through i 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: *Short answer: No.* <- This is incorrect.

Long answer: you probably don't want to use STRSQL anyway.  Use iNavigator (also on its way out) or IBM i Access for Web, which has a database interface.  Another IBM offering is [Data Studio](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/data-studio).  Alternatively, you could use any number of third party database tools like [SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) to do design work or for ad hoc queries.  Basically, anything that uses ODBC / JDBC will work.

As a side note, the platform hasn't been called AS/400 for 20 years.  Google searches for AS/400 are increasingly returning worse and worse results.  A more modern name (only 10 years defunct) is iSeries.  The current operating system is called IBM i, and the IBM web site is called the [Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i/welcome).  It's true that 'IBM i' doesn't yield the best search results, but that will never change unless we start using the term on the internet :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use STRSQL all the time to prove an SQL statement either in my RPG or Web-based pgm.
I don't like clearing the historical statements because sometimes I find a hint, or a technique that I may need to reference again at some point.
With all that being said...
If your screen is "crowded" and you just want a brand new screen - simply page-down.

Comment: If value is found in having the past statements, then be sure to save them to a database file that gets backed-up as part of B&R for DR. The SQL *session* objects are stored in a library that is explicitly **excluded** from B&R, so in the event of DR, all sessions are lost. Also, if the session fills, or a *bad error* transpires for which the utility believes an appropriate resolution is to delete the session, then again, that data is lost for lack of any expectation of B&R.